# Errors on PL/SQL Queries with Cursor Parameters (LOOP FETCH) and For loop Subqueries

Tags: oracle, plsql, parameters, cursor, oracle-apex

I want to display the value of country_id, country_name,region_id, highest_elevation,date_of_independence, population
where the highest_elevation >1000 AND <1000 AND population >5000000 also the country who has an independence day. 
The important thing, the output of the region_id must be >1.

So far, I've tried to make the PL/SQL queries of it. But, I found errors. I made 2 variations of the queries. The Cursor with parameters use LOOP and FETCH 
also the cursor with parameters use subqueries and FOR LOOP.

Here's the code for the subqueries :

```
--pakai subqueries tp gak bisa
v_regid countries.region_id%TYPE;
CURSOR cur_con (pregid NUMBER) IS
SELECT country_id,country_name,region_id,highest_elevation,date_of_independence, population
FROM countries
WHERE region_id = pregid 
AND highest_elevation >1000 AND highest_elevation<1000 AND population >5000000 AND date_of_independence IS NOT NULL;
BEGIN
FOR con_rec IN cur_con (v_regid) LOOP
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( ' ' );
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( ' ============================================= ' );
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( ' ID Negara :  ' || con_rec.country_id );
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( ' Nama Negara : ' || con_rec.country_name );
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( ' ID Region : ' || con_rec.region_id );
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( ' Ketinggian yang tertinggi : ' || con_rec.highest_elevation );
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( ' Hari kemerdekaan : '|| con_rec.date_of_independence );
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( ' Populasi : ' ||con_rec.population );
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( ' ============================================= ' );
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( ' ' );
END LOOP;
END;
```

The error of the first queries : ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

And here's the code for the Cursor with parameters use LOOP and FETCH

```
--pakai cursor n parameter biasa
DECLARE
v_conid countries.country_id%TYPE;
v_coname countries.country_id%TYPE;
v_regid countries.region_id%TYPE;
v_he countries.highest_elevation%type;
v_doi countries.date_of_independence%TYPE;
v_pop countries.population%TYPE;
CURSOR cur_con (pregid NUMBER) IS
SELECT country_id,country_name,region_id,highest_elevation,date_of_independence, population
FROM countries
WHERE region_id = pregid 
AND highest_elevation >1000 AND highest_elevation<1000 AND population >5000000 AND date_of_independence IS NOT NULL;
reccon cur_con%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
SELECT country_id,country_name,region_id,highest_elevation,date_of_independence, population INTO v_conid,v_coname,v_regid,v_he,v_doi,v_pop
FROM countries;
OPEN cur_con(v_regid);
LOOP
FETCH cur_con INTO reccon;
EXIT WHEN cur_con%NOTFOUND;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( ' ' );
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( ' ============================================= ' );
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( ' ID Negara :  ' || reccon.country_id );
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( ' Nama Negara : ' || reccon.country_name );
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( ' ID Region : ' || reccon.region_id );
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( ' Ketinggian yang tertinggi : ' || reccon.highest_elevation );
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( ' Hari kemerdekaan : '|| reccon.date_of_independence );
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( ' Populasi : ' ||reccon.population );
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( ' ============================================= ' );
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( ' ' );
END LOOP;
CLOSE cur_con;
end;
```

The error for the second queries : ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows

What's wrong with my queries? Please help me

Answer (score 1):

Your second code has issues but code 1 looks ok to me. See both the correct working version:

Code 1:

```
DECLARE
  --pakai subqueries tp gak bisa
  --v_regid countries.region_id%TYPE;

  CURSOR cur_con (pregid NUMBER)
  IS 
    SELECT country_id,
      country_name,
      region_id,
      highest_elevation,
      date_of_independence,
      population
    FROM countries
    WHERE region_id           = pregid
    AND highest_elevation     >1000
    AND highest_elevation     <1000
    AND population            >5000000
    AND date_of_independence IS NOT NULL;
BEGIN
  FOR con_rec IN cur_con (v_regid)--<--Assuming you pass value of v_regid
  LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( ' ' );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( ' ============================================= ' );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( ' ID Negara :  ' || con_rec.country_id );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( ' Nama Negara : ' || con_rec.country_name );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( ' ID Region : ' || con_rec.region_id );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( ' Ketinggian yang tertinggi : ' || con_rec.highest_elevation );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( ' Hari kemerdekaan : '|| con_rec.date_of_independence );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( ' Populasi : ' ||con_rec.population );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( ' ============================================= ' );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( ' ' );
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Code 2 : - There is no need to execute select query twice. Also when you do the `Select` inside the begin block, there is no filter condition, so query is retruning multiple rows and you try to assign multiple rows to a single variable. Hence you get the issue: `ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows`. See below

```
--pakai cursor n parameter biasa
DECLARE 
  CURSOR cur_con (pregid NUMBER)
  IS
    SELECT country_id,
      country_name,
      region_id,
      highest_elevation,
      date_of_independence,
      population
    FROM countries
    WHERE region_id           = pregid
    AND highest_elevation     >1000
    AND highest_elevation     <1000
    AND population            >5000000
    AND date_of_independence IS NOT NULL;

  reccon cur_con%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN 
  OPEN cur_con(v_regid);
  LOOP
    FETCH cur_con INTO reccon;
    EXIT  WHEN cur_con%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( ' ' );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( ' ============================================= ' );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( ' ID Negara :  ' || reccon.country_id );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( ' Nama Negara : ' || reccon.country_name );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( ' ID Region : ' || reccon.region_id );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( ' Ketinggian yang tertinggi : ' || reccon.highest_elevation );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( ' Hari kemerdekaan : '|| reccon.date_of_independence );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( ' Populasi : ' ||reccon.population );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( ' ============================================= ' );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( ' ' );
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE cur_con;
END;
```

Comment: Okay well, both the queries can compiled well but, it didn't give information. The output is :

Statement processed.

0.01 seconds

For me the algorithm is already true, but why it didnt give a result? Oh ya, btw I run my queries with Oracle Apex Web because, the schema is there. Is there any difference between run in Oracle Apex and Oracle 11g?

Comment: You need to check if you had set serverout on or put dbms_output.enable in your block.

Comment: As I said before, I ran my queries on Oracle Apex web because, all of the schemas are on there.Of course, If I use on Oracle 11g, I must put the serveroutput  .FYI : I followed your queries and I already ran your queries but, the output still "Statement processed. 0.01 seconds"

Comment: @MayaRetnosari Not very sure but it seems error lies with Apex setting.  If oracle is compiled then you must look at Apex end,